# My Console Application is trying to open in the browser when I click the play button

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, console-application

I have a solution with 2 projects in Visual Studio 2013. The first is a WCF application, the second is a Console application I've recently added.

On the console app, instead of the play button saying 'Start', it says 'Google Chrome', with the other options appearing to be web-browsers. When I run it, I get at 'HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden' message in the browser.

My Console app has a `class program` with `static void Main()`.

How can I get my console app to run in a console?

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the console app as the start-up project.

Project > Set StartUp Projects > Single StartUP Project > [Console App Name]